# Trying initialize a two-dimensional array of structs and getting read access violation exception thrown

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I have a structure that represents an n×n checkers board.
And I have the method `createAndInitBoard` which would return a two-dimensional array of size n×n of `cell`, i.e `cell *`*`. The function should allocate the required memory and initialize each cell with a color and a status.

The following code was given:

```
enum cellColor { bright, dark };
enum cellStatus { emptyC, whitePiece, blackPiece };
struct cell {
    cellColor color;
    cellStatus status;
};
cellColor computeColor(int r, int c) {
    if ((r % 2 == 0 && c % 2 == 0) || (r % 2 != 0 && c % 2 != 0)) {
        return bright;
    }
    return dark;
}
```

So far I've manage to do the following :

```
cell** createAndInitBoard(int n) {
    cell** B = {};
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            B[i][j].color = computeColor(i, j);
            if ((i % 2 == 0 && j % 2 == 0) || (i % 2 != 0 && j % 2 != 0)) {
                B[i][j].status = emptyC;
            }
            else {
                if (i < 3) {
                    B[i][j].status = blackPiece;
                }
                if (i > 4) {
                    B[i][j].status = whitePiece;
                }
            }            
        }
    }
    return B;
}
```

Of course, for now, this would work just for a board of 8×8. I'm also trying to come up with some condition that could compute an n×n board.
But I'm getting an error and I think it was to do with the way that I'm initializing the cell.

```
cell** B = {};
```

Any ideas on how can I fix this and even how could I improve my code?

Comment: What error are you getting exactly?

Comment: @cigien When I'm trying to compile the code in the format above I don't get any error. But while I was debugging I got this: Exception thrown: read access violation at this line  cell** B = {};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition and initialization

```
cell** B = {};
```

will [*zero-initialize*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization) the pointer `B`. Zero-initializing a pointer means it will be a *null* pointer. Null pointers can't be dereferenced (with e.g. array indexing).

The natural C++ solution is to use a vector instead (since the size isn't known at compile-time):

```
std::vector<std::vector<cell>> B(n, std::vector<cell>(n));
```

Otherwise you need to do dynamic allocation using `new[]`:

```
cell** B = new cell*[n];
for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    B[i] = new cell[n];
};
```

But then you need to remember to `delete[]` all the pointers later (*smart pointer* solve that deletion problem though).

Comment: I tried the dynamic allocation approach and It's working as I was intended. I have one question. What if I don't delete the pointers after?

Comment: @AndreiCălugăr If you don't free memory you allocate (or generally don't release any resource you acquire) that's a *leak*.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations. Very helpful, I managed to finish the problem :D